# srcset of Image puts height to 30px in Edge

Tags: microsoft-edge, responsive-images, srcset

For this page, my clients notices that the images are cropped up to the height of 30px, keeping the same width. 
https://www.agricamp.be/producten/akkerbouw/meststoffen/kalkmeststoffen/

After investigation, it's a problem with the Edge browser. There's a ticket over here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/7778808/

It's a bizar problem, on that client pc: when i go to developper tools and remove the srcset in code, the image is back to normal. When i refresh the page, the image stays OK. Even when it has the srcset back again in it's code. The problem is very random, not all images are affected. 
There is a caching plugin activated: WP Rocket. Maybe a caching thing?

It seems that Microsoft doesn't do anything to fix it. Ticket is a few months old. Is there someone here who has the same issue, and found a solution.
The only solution (imo) is to strip the srcset (which is WordPress default functionality), but i rather won't do this.

Comment: Are you serious? The problem is known for almost a year and it still hasn't been adressed? Wow! Microsoft is proving to have produced another inferior browser.

I am currently downloading a virtual machine to test if I can reproduce the problem, because a client of mine has been complaining about this aswell.